# Count records per group within date lag

Tags: r

I have a large dataset structured as follows

```
dat <- data.frame("Date" = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-20", "2017-04-15", "2017-11-03", "2018-01-03", "2019-12-12", "2020-03-07", "2014-05-19", "2009-07-03", "2010-02-04"), 
                  "Region" = c("Adelaide", "Albany", "Albany", "Albany", "Albany", "Albany", "Albany", "Middleton", "Alice Springs", "Alice Springs"))

dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

**For each record I would like to count the number records if they are within the previous 12 months and only if they are within the same region. Any help in achieving this would be greatly appreciated?**

My final dataset should look the same as the original dataset but with the addition of the below count column

```
dat$Count <- c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

This count column shows that for the first record in the dataset there are no other records from the same region that occurred in the previous 12 months, however for 5th record in the dataset there are 3 other records that occurred in the previous 12 months within the same region.

I have tried a range of solutions in `dplyr` using `group_by()`, `count()` and `summarise()` but haven't come close to my intention yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `Region` you can take the difference of the current date with all other dates and count the number of dates that are between 0 and 365 days.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  mutate(Count = map_dbl(row_number(), 
                   ~sum(between(Date[.x] - Date[-.x], 0, 365)))) %>%
  ungroup

#    Date       Region        Count
#   <date>     <chr>         <dbl>
# 1 2017-01-01 Adelaide          0
# 2 2017-01-20 Albany            0
# 3 2017-04-15 Albany            1
# 4 2017-11-03 Albany            2
# 5 2018-01-03 Albany            3
# 6 2019-12-12 Albany            0
# 7 2020-03-07 Albany            1
# 8 2014-05-19 Middleton         0
# 9 2009-07-03 Alice Springs     0
#10 2010-02-04 Alice Springs     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  mutate(a = accumulate(c(0, diff(Date)), ~if(.x+.y < 365).x+.y else 0))%>%
  group_by(Count = cumsum(a==0)) %>%
  mutate(Count = seq(n())- 1, a = NULL)
         
  Date       Region        Count
   <date>     <chr>         <dbl>
 1 2017-01-01 Adelaide          0
 2 2017-01-20 Albany            0
 3 2017-04-15 Albany            1
 4 2017-11-03 Albany            2
 5 2018-01-03 Albany            3
 6 2019-12-12 Albany            0
 7 2020-03-07 Albany            1
 8 2014-05-19 Middleton         0
 9 2009-07-03 Alice Springs     0
10 2010-02-04 Alice Springs     1
```

You could also do:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)
dat[, Count := c(0, diff(Date)), Region][,
      Count := rowid(cumsum(replace(Count, Count>365, 0) == 0))-1]
```

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu, but your first suggestion does not work for me. If I run my first section of code to load ```dat``` and classify ```dat$Date``` and then I run your first section of code I get ```dat$Count``` as the following vector ```c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7)```